# Error in installing Mapr

Tags: hadoop, mapr

hi I am trying to install MapR on ubuntu 12.04 precise but facing some isuues. I followd below link for installation

```
http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Quick+Installation+Guide
```

I followed all the steps mentioned in the link Below is the error i am getting

```
* 16:15:50 Interrogating Node(s), Validating Prerequisites, and Starting Install
* 16:15:53 Installing Extra Package Repositories If Needed
* 16:15:55 Detecting Operating System
* 16:15:57 Installing Prerequisite Packages for Ubuntu/Debian
* 16:16:02 Detecting Operating System
* 16:16:06 Configuring Firewall for Ubuntu/Debian
* 16:16:08 Creating MapR User
* 16:16:23 Installing and Configuring NTP Service
* 16:16:29 Installing OpenJDK Packages If Needed
* 16:16:35 Detecting Operating System
* 16:16:37 Initializing MapR Repository for Ubuntu/Debian
ubuntu: error getting key id from url: http://package.mapr.com/releases/pub/gnugpg.key
failed: [ubuntu] => {"failed": true, "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call   last):\n  File     \"/home/pcadmin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1405939599.14-281315531843819/apt_key\", line 158, in download_key\n    return rsp.read()\nAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'\n"}

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
Host: ubuntu had 1 failures
Control Nodes have failures. Please fix the failures and re-run the installation.
```

Please help

Comment: If you're looking to play around with MapR, they also supply a [pre-installed VM](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/MapR+Sandbox+for+Hadoop). Way easier to setup.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar issue to this when installing elasticsearch - in my case it was caused by a combination of an egress-filtering firewall and no proxy being set.  Check your Ansible proxy settings (if relevant), and that http://package.mapr.com/releases/pub/gnugpg.key is accessible from the machine in question.